# Импорт данных в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Есть pandas DF, содержащий записи о людях. Проблема заключается в том, что есть строки, которые совпадают почти полностью и нужно их объединить в одну строку так, как показано на примере ниже. (Столбец, по которому записи не совпадают, ОДИН).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, эффективный способ (не перебором) объединить записи об одном человеке в одну запись, при этом по не совпадающему полю взять сумму значений.

---

**Пример данных:**

Иванов И.И | 30 | M | 16 |

Иванов И.И | 30 | M | 18 |

**Нужно получить:**

Иванов И.И | 30 | M | 34 |

---

Нужно простенькое решение, которое сработает на DF в тысяч сто записей.
Спасибо.

Comment: Добавте в вопрос код и пример данных.

Comment: Посмотри этот [тред](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583668/merge-2-dataframes-in-pandas-join-on-some-columns-sum-up-others).

Comment: Вы знаете заранее имя столбца по которому записи не совпадают? Можете привести пример ваших данных, например вывод `print(df.head())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [68]: df
Out[68]:
    name  id sex  val
0  Name1  30   M   16
1  Name2  31   F   21
2  Name1  30   M   18
3  Name2  31   F   22
4  Name3  33   M   11

In [69]: col = 'val'

In [70]: df.groupby(df.columns.drop(col).tolist(), as_index=False).sum()
Out[70]:
    name  id sex  val
0  Name1  30   M   34
1  Name2  31   F   43
2  Name3  33   M   11
```

Замер времени выполнения для DF с 500.000 строк:

```
In [79]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [80]: df.shape
Out[80]: (500000, 4)

In [81]: pd.options.display.max_rows = 10

In [82]: df
Out[82]:
         name  id sex  val
0       Name1  30   M   16
1       Name2  31   F   21
2       Name1  30   M   18
3       Name2  31   F   22
4       Name3  33   M   11
...       ...  ..  ..  ...
499995  Name1  30   M   16
499996  Name2  31   F   21
499997  Name1  30   M   18
499998  Name2  31   F   22
499999  Name3  33   M   11

[500000 rows x 4 columns]

In [83]: %timeit df.groupby(df.columns.drop(col).tolist(), as_index=False).sum()
10 loops, best of 3: 66.3 ms per loop
```